# Сanvas fabricjs рамка изоражения

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Привет, парни, подскажите как сделать, что бы рамка изображения не исчезала, когда я ее увожу за фон другого изображения?
То есть, есть пример - jsfiddle.net/gorelov/hLj6tmq8 Когда текст передвигаю за рамку телефона, то у меня пропадает изображение и сама рамка, а нужно что бы она осталась, как тут jsfiddle.net/gorelov/m8ac9nhn - но этот пример мне не подходит, мне нужно модифицировать первый пример, подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает!

Comment: А где твой код?

Comment: Я приложил ссылку на jsfiddle
Подумал так будет легче
jsfiddle.net/gorelov/hLj6tmq8
jsfiddle.net/gorelov/m8ac9nhn

Answer (score 0):

Все, решил. Проблема была вот в чем.
У меня в примере картинка телефона накладывалась через метод setOverlayImage. И он не давал возможности сделать что мне нужно.
Я поменял его на  setBackgroundImage. И готово, пример, который мне помог jsfiddle.net/gs1L69fj/9